# Assigning roles to members in Firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I am adding members in my Firebase project through console with the role of "Project Editor" which have all view permissions acc to docs. But by login as a member I am not able to see the Analytics. I tried changing role to "Project Owner" but still Analytics are not visible.

I am working with Firebase for the first time and new with the roles concept. Please help if anyone have solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by the term "not visible", are you seeing a plain blank screen or the dashboards are there but no data yet?

I'd suggest you to try the following workarounds:

1. If you have multiple Google accounts logged in at the same time, please logged them out and use only the account for Firebase. Also, use Google Chrome incognito mode.
2. Turn off Ad blockers or check if the Analytics domain is disabled by your Network administrator.
3. Open the Google Chrome developer mode, then check if there's any error logs or stack trace on the console. Reach out to the Firebase Support team by creating a ticket [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/account-services/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @looptheloop88 for your answer. it pushed me to think differently that may be the problem is not in my process but in the sources that I am using like my gmail id that I used as a Project Editor role.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution

I tried other gmail id that is with "gmail.com" domain rather than my "company_name.com" domain and the analytics is now visible that is previously only blank white screen.

It is because in company domain there are some restriction on user access.